# How can I delete stickers on viber?

Tags: downloading, viber-messenger

How can I delete downloaded stickers on viber? I downloaded there a few, and the last one I wanted to download was not possible because there was not enough room in my storage space (still isn't). Now, it says every single time when I open my phone,

> there is not enough room in the storage space available to complete this action.  Please clear some space and try again.

And I am not even downloading anything, it keeps doing it itself. Whatever I do, the window pops up and again, I have to close it.   What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Go to your profile in viber "You"
At the bottom of page, Go to "market sticker"
At the top right corner, you see "settings"
select it, & you can "on/off" your stickers.
It's as simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Viber product page](http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1362371-viber-sticker-market-for-android#Can%20I%20delete%20sticker%20packages?):

> **Can I delete sticker packages?**
>
> Once you have downloaded a sticker package, it will remain on your
>   device. However, you have the option of disabling sticker packages
>   that you do not want displayed in your sticker menu. ​
>
> - Enter the Sticker Market
> - Select the `gear` icon
> - Uncheck the box next to the packages you do not want to displayed in your sticker menu

Answer (score 0):

Go to sticker market and deselect sticker you don't want. Get a file manager that shows hidden files (the ones starting with a .). Go to viber/media/.stickers folder and delete everything in it. You have just deleted "all" stickers. Open viber and the stickers still selected will automagically download again. It takes a while but they all come back :-)

Answer (score 0):

As of now THERE IS NO delete option.